# When a 3-strand pretzel link is an unknot?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I want to find any (nontrivial) necessary (and also sufficient, if possible) condition to determine whether $(p,q,r)$-pretzel link is equivalent to the trivial knot, where $p$, $q$, $r$ are integers.

I tried to find necessary conditions using knot polynomials, but for me, the calculations were so complicated.

Are there any already-known sources/references about solutions to it?

Comment: A paper of Kim and Lee appears to resolve this for the case of knots (though after reading it, not general links, though roughly the same arguments might work) by calculating the Jones Polynomial and genera of pretzel knots (and the genera of some pretzel links). If the paper is to be believed under naive reading, the only pretzel knots with nontrivial $p, q, r$ which are the unknot are $(p, \pm 1, \mp 1)$. A paper of Landvoy is cited for calculating the Jones Polynomial of the knots, and since the paper of Landvoy also mentions links it may be possible to classify all trivial pretzel links.

Comment: Related MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42056/trivial-pretzel-links